# Calculating $P(2\leq X\leq 4)$ for an exponentially random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

While calculating P(2≤X≤4), for an exponential random distribution, the solution says, 
$P(2\leq X\leq 4) = F(4)-F(2)$, where F denotes the CDF.

My version is, 
P(2≤X≤4) = P(22) and P(X≤4), i.e.
1-P(X≤2) and  P(X≤4)
{1-F(2)} * F(4), presuming they are independent event.

I know it is wrong, but please clarify, where I am commiting mistake in this approach.

Thanks

Comment: What is $P(22)$?  The rest of the description is muddy.  What events are independent?  You need an equation $P(2\le X\le 4)=$.

Comment: The entire text is not coming once I post the question.

Comment: While calculating P(2≤X≤4), for an exponential random distribution, the solution says, 
P(2≤X≤4) = F(4)-F(2), where F denotes the CDF.

My version is, 
P(2≤X≤4) = P(2<X≤4) as P(X=2) is zero for a continuous random variable. We can write,
 P(2<X≤4) = P(2<X) and P(X≤4), i.e.
P(X>2) and P(X≤4), i.e.
1-P(X≤2) and  P(X≤4) which equals
{1-F(2)} * F(4), presuming 2<X and X≤4 are independent events. 

I know it is wrong, but please clarify,  I am commiting mistake in this approach.

Thanks

Comment: Very simply put, the events are not independent

Comment: Basic error: $X\gt 2$ and $X\le 4$ are NOT independent events, since they are both about the same random variable.  I suggest you fix original statement - $P(22)$?